# Bootstrap with CSS Transition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, grid, hover, css-transitions

Hey so I've been trying to figure this out for ages and I've been searching for a solution for hours! and tried pretty much everything I've come across here on Stack overflow and other various websites.

I'm not sure whether my problem is Pixel rounding, Bootstrap, or CSS transitions.

It seems this is a common problem, and its a 1px gap between my image grid especially on browser resize.

[image]

The grid itself works perfectly and scales fine, however I've added some code for the hover caption and that seems to cause the issue from what I've tried.

The Hover state code was located from here : [Image caption Hover animation](http://hasinhayder.github.io/ImageCaptionHoverAnimation/index.html)

and this is a working example of what is happening - [Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/Ew5Hle4f7L#)

I tried adding the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` which someone recommended, but I am completely stumped, I get the same problem in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

`clip: rect(10px, 10px, 10px, 10px);` into your
`.hovereffect img`

than add this property and value
`-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(square, white, black);`
into your `.hovereffect`

This should work.